# Syntax error in the Constructor.  The Keyword class was used and then removed

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, object

I am doing a GUI interface.  When i am creating an object i am getting an error message can anyone see what i have forgotten to do ?  The error message is in the MainApp under the comment Building an object for subClass.  Thanks in advance.
I have made a mistake of putting class(class is a keyword in java) in the constructor:
public class subClass() 
        {
class was then removed to prevent the error occurring.

//Imports.
    //MainApp.

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class MainApp 
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        //Building an object for subClass.
        subClass class = new subClass();
        class.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        class.setSize(275,275);
        class.setVisible(true);



    }
}


//Imports.
//subclass.

import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

//
public class subClass extends JFrame 
{
    private JLabel item1;

    //
    public subClass() 
    {
        // Sets the Title of the window.
        super("Title");
        // Sets the layout of the window. FlowLayout is the default layout.
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        item1 = new JLabel("This is a sentence.");
        item1.setToolTipText("This is going to show up on hover.");
        add(item1);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  subClass class = new subClass();
```

`class` is a Java keyword. You can't use it as an identifier.

Answer (score 2):

`class` is a reserved word. You can only use it when defining a class or accessing a class literal. Rename your variable to something different, such as `clazz`.

Answer (score 1):

I have made a mistake of putting class(class is a keyword in java) in the construtor: public class subClass() {